# Downloading multiple Landsat images from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a problem downloading multiple Landsat images from GEE using the code below:

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-aahmadsha06/assets/Nanjing");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T2_TOA")
print(dataset.size())
var city = roi.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2', 'Nanjing'))
var filter_region = dataset.filterBounds(city)
print(filter_region.size())
var filter_metadata = filter_region.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',1)
print(filter_metadata.size())
var filter_date = filter_metadata.filterDate('2000-01-01','2012-05-30')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2, 5,'month'))
                  .map(function(a){
      return a.set('year', ee.Image(a).date().get('year'))
    })

var list = ee.List([])
 for(var a=2000; a<2013; a++) {
   var filL5 = filter_date.filterMetadata('year','equals', a).median()
    var L5final = filL5.set('year', a). set('product', 'L5')
   
    list=list.add(L5final)
 }

//print(list)
//var finalCol = ee.ImageCollection(list).map(function(a){
//         return a.set('bands', ee.Image (a). bandNames(). length())
//         })
//    //   .filterMetadata('bands', 'equals' 19)
//print(finalCol)

var final_image = filter_date.median()
var study_area = final_image.clip(city)
for(var a=2000; a<2013; a++){
  Map.addLayer(study_area, imageVisParam, 'years'+''+a)
 // Map.addLayer(filter_date.filterMetadata('year','equals', a), {}, 'years'+''+a)
}
//print(filter_date.size())

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset,
  description: 'landsat_5',
  scale: 10,
  region: city
});
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit to improve the code formatting etc, but it would be worth adding what problem you're facing with the above code.

Comment: Don't use for-loops. They slow down the GEE API. Use evaluate method instead. There are many examples in this site.